# Allowance in a smart contract

Tags: solidity

I have a smart contract that takes in tokens. I was curious if those tokens owned could be added to the allowance of another owner?

When they submit the tokens, I verify allowance and transferFrom. However when I disburse the funds I then have to have them call a new allowance to show the added difference. Obviously they can see the funds in their Wallet balance but for this example I wanted to increase the allowance in the smart contract.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by this part:

> However when I disburse the funds I then have to have them call a new allowance to show the added difference.

You can use a regular `transfer` to send funds from your contract. No allowance is required.

If the concern is that funds are coming back and future transfers *in* are not approved, there are two generalized approach you could consider. The scenario I have in mind in tokens in the user wallets at all times, but users are expected to send tokens more than once, so you want to reduce the approvals.

1. Just keep the tokens in your contract until they want to withdraw funds from the system. You would usually keep your own ledger of liabilities, i.e. user balances in the contract. It goes deposit, participate, participate, participate, withdraw.
2. Many DeFi projects encourage users to "approve" an "infinite" amount, once. In practice, the amount is 2**256-1 which is `uint INFINITE = ~uint(0);` (bitwise flip zeroes to ones). Not precisely "infinity" but it might as well be because (usually) no one will ever have that much money.

Hope it helps